# rsync keep specific folder with its contents and the structure, exclude any files outside the folder

Tags: rsync

my file system looks like:

source/

```
folder1/
  subfolder/
    contents
  other_subfolders
  file1
  file2
folder2/
  subfolder/
    contents
  other_subfolders
  file1
  file2
folder3/
  subfolder/
    contents
  other_subfolders
  file1
  file2
file1
file2
```

What I want to copy is pretty much only this:

```
folder1/
  subfolder/
    contents
folder2/
  subfolder/
    contents
folder3/
  subfolder/
    contents
```

i.e. I only want to keep

- folder structure
- copy over subfolders with their contents
- ignore any files outside subfolders or any other folders outside subfolders

Currently, I'm trying:

```
$cd destination
$rsync -atvr --include="*/subfolder/" --exclude="*" source/ .
```

By putting in `--exclude="*"` I hope to exclude everything except what I put in include, which is `*/subfolder/`, that is, a folder called subfolder being inside any highest-level folder in the source...

However, no files are being ever copied. Why? What am I missing?

I also tried

```
$cd destination
$rsync -atvr --include="*/subfolder/" --exclude="*/*" source/ .
```

But that did this:

```
folder1/
  subfolder/
folder2/
  subfolder/
folder3/
  subfolder/
file1
file2
```

i.e. kept files in source (outside folders), created the desired subfolders, but did not copy anything inside them.

Edit: at Siva's request, after putting in `rsync -av --include='/' --include='/subfolder**' --exclude='*' source/ .`

I get:

To access the system:

1) If not using ssh-keys, please enter your TACC password at the password prompt
2) At the TACC Token prompt, enter your 6-digit code followed by .

```
Password:
TACC Token Code:
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
receiving incremental file list
./

sent 59 bytes  received 104 bytes  10.52 bytes/sec
total size is 3,242  speedup is 19.89
```

But I promise, all those warnings have nothing to do with the problem at hand and pop up every time I try to access the server in whatever way (ssh, scp, rsync, ...).

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the potential complexity of `--include` and `--exclude` by using relative paths to specify the source fileset you want to copy

**Scenario**

We create your example directory and file structure underneath a topmost directory `src`. We will be copying the selection to the topmost directory `dst`

```
mkdir -p src/folder{1,2,3}/{subfolder,other_subfolders} dst
touch src/folder{1,2,3}/subfolder/contents src/{folder{1,2,3}/,}file{1,2}
find src | LC_ALL=C sort

rsync --dry-run -avR src/./folder*/*/* dst/
```

**Output** (from `rsync`)

```
sending incremental file list
folder1/
folder1/subfolder/
folder1/subfolder/contents
folder2/
folder2/subfolder/
folder2/subfolder/contents
folder3/
folder3/subfolder/
folder3/subfolder/contents
```

The `/./` marks the point at which the remainder of the source path is to be used at the destination. Remove `--dry-run` to make it perform the chosen operations.

Comment: For this I get the following error: bash: /bin/rsync: Argument list too long

Comment: @user16320 you have way more folders than you suggested in your question

Comment: I have 21 folders

Answer (score 0):

From man:

> if the pattern contains a / (not counting a trailing /), then it is matched against the full pathname, **including any leading directories**.

Try as,

```
 rsync -av --include='/' --include='/subfolder**' --exclude='*' source/ destination/
```

Comment: This still does not copy anything...

Comment: can u share the output of the command...

Comment: (A lot of warnings pertaining to the particular server that are shown when executing any command) and then: "sent 59 bytes  received 104 bytes  10.52 bytes/sec
total size is 3,242  speedup is 19.89"

Comment: plz share in question...

Comment: I added an edit: I pasted the warnings with the output of rsync in the question.